# What does it mean for a sequence $x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}, . . .$ of configurations in $X$ to converge to another configuration $x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

> Provide a concrete description of what it means for a sequence $x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}
> , . . .$ of configurations in $X$ to converge to another configuration $x$.

We can write $x^{(1)} = \left(x_1^{(1)}, x_2^{(1)}, ...\right)$, $x^{(2)} = \left(x_1^{(2)}, x_2^{(2)}, ...\right)$, and $x = (x_1, x_2, ...)$. So for the sequence $x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}, . . .$ of configurations in $X$ to converge to another configuration $x$, means that $x_1^{(1)}$ and $x_1^{(2)}$ both converge to $x_1$, $x_2^{(1)}$ and $x_2^{(2)}$ both converge to $x_2$, and so on...
Is it correct?

Comment: Can you precise what is $X$ and what is called a "configuration" of $X$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you are talking about the same space $X$ as in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828711/verify-that-every-cylinder-set-is-clopen). The convergence is with respect to the topology of $X$ defined in that question. This means that the sequence $\left\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ converges to $x$ if and only if for each open nbhd $U$ of $x$ there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x^{(n)}\in U$ whenever $n\ge m$. The cylinder sets $B(w)$ defined in your previous question are a base for the topology of $X$, so we can simplify this a little: $\left\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ converges to $x$ if and only if for each cylinder set $B(w)$ containing $x$ there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x^{(n)}\in B(w)$ whenever $n\ge m$.

Now what are the cylinder sets containing $x$? Assuming that $x=x_1 x_2 x_3\ldots$, they are the sets $B(\lambda)$, $B(x_1)$, $B(x_1x_2)$, $B(x_1x_2x_3)$, and so on. Thus, $\left\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ converges to $x$ if and only if for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x^{(n)}\in B(x_1x_2\ldots x_k)$ whenever $n\ge m$. And now we’re almost there:

> $\left\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ converges to $x$ if and only if for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x_1^{(n)}x_2^{(n)}\ldots x_k^{(n)}=x_1x_2\ldots x_k$ whenever $n\ge m$.

In other words, for any $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, all of the $x^{(n)}$ from some point on have the same first $k$ terms as $x$.

Note that it makes no sense to say that $x_1^{(1)}$ converges to $x_1$: $x_1^{(1)}$ is simply one element of the alphabet $\Sigma$ and is therefore not something that can converge.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood everything. Can you give me an example of a converging sequence in which the configurations $x^{(n)}$ (for $n = 1, 2, . . .$) are all distinct?

Comment: @JOJO: You’re very welcome. Let $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, and for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $$x^{(n)}=\underbrace{11\ldots 11}_{n\text{ ones}}\underbrace{000\ldots}_{\text{all zeroes}}\;.$$ This sequence converges to the configuration $111\ldots$ (all ones).

Answer (score 1):

To go on with the product topology as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3828807/4280): a standard fact about products is that $x^{(n)} \to x$ iff the sequence converges coordinatewise, so

$$\forall k: x^{(n)}_k \to x_k \text{ as } n \to \infty \text{ in } \Sigma$$

and as $\Sigma$ is discrete a sequence there is convergent iff it is eventually constant so

$$x^{(n)} \to x \iff \forall k: \exists N_k \in \Bbb N: \forall n \ge N_k: x^{(n)}_k  = x_k$$

so in words, for every coordinate the configuration must eventually have the same stable value $x_k$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood everything. Can you give me an example of a converging sequence in which the configurations $x^{(n)}$ (for n=1,2,...) are all distinct?

Comment: @JOJO sure the configurations $0000\ldots, 1000\ldots, 11000\ldots, 1110000\ldots,$ etc. converge to the all $1$ configuration $1111\ldots$ in this topology.